# Conditional distribution of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: probability

Suppose

$$\begin{bmatrix}x_i\\z_i\end{bmatrix} \sim \mathcal{N}\left(\begin{bmatrix}\mu\\0\end{bmatrix},\begin{bmatrix}I_p\sigma^2 + BB' & B\\B' & I_q\end{bmatrix}\right)$$

, where $x_i$ has length $p$, $z_i$ has length $q$, $B$ has dimension $p\times q$, and $I$ has dimension $q$.

I am interested in finding the conditional distribution of $z_i\mid x_i$. I followed [page 10 on this notes](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~pabbeel/cs287-fa11/slides/Gaussians-v2.pdf) but get different answer from the correct ones.

Basically, here we have $\Sigma_{XX} = I\sigma^2 + BB', \Sigma_{XY} = B,\Sigma_{YY}=I$. So the covariance should be

$$\Sigma_{YY} - \Sigma_{YX} \Sigma_{XX}^{-1} \Sigma_{XY} = I - B' (I\sigma^2 + BB')^{-1} B$$

But the answer I have is $$\sigma^2 (I\sigma^2 + BB')^{-1}$$

, and I don't see why those two are the same thing.

Also, using the formula, the mean should be

$$0+B'(I\sigma^2 + BB')^{-1}(x_i - \mu)$$

, but the answer is

$$(I_q\sigma^2 + B'B)^{-1} B' (x_i-\mu)$$

Comment: The answer you have is incorrect. Quick sanity check: the covariance $\sigma^2(\sigma^2 I + BB')^{-1}$ has dimension $p\times p$, but the correct dimension has to be $q\times q$. The mean also does not have a valid matrix multiplication ($p\times p$ matrix with $q\times p$ matrix with $p\times 1$ vector).

Comment: @JirapatSamranvedhya Right, just realized that I dropped all the subscript of $I$ so probably messed up dimension somewhere, and I'm checking now :|

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing your notation a little
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{zz} = \mathbf{I}_q, \qquad \mathbf{\Sigma}_{zx}=\mathbf{B}', \qquad \mathbf{\Sigma}_{xx} =\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_p + \mathbf{BB'} 
$$
then as you note the covariance is given by
$$
\mathbf{\Sigma}_{z|x} =\mathbf{\Sigma}_{zz} - \mathbf{\Sigma}_{zx}\mathbf{\Sigma}_{xx}^{-1}\mathbf{\Sigma}_{xz} =\mathbf{I}_q - \mathbf{B}'\left(\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_p+\mathbf{BB'}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}, 
$$
but as a special case of the [Woodbury Matrix identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) we have
$$
\left(\mathbf{I}_q+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{B'B} \right)^{-1} = \mathbf{I}_q - \mathbf{B}'\left(\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_p+\mathbf{BB'}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B},
$$
which is quickly checked in this case letting $\mathbf{M}=\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_p + \mathbf{BB}'$ then
\begin{align*}
\left(\mathbf{I}_q+\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{B'B}\right)\left(\mathbf{I}_q - \mathbf{B}'\left(\sigma^2\mathbf{I}_p+\mathbf{BB'}\right)^{-1}\mathbf{B}\right) &= \mathbf{I}_q - \mathbf{B}' \left(-\mathbf{M}^{-1} + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{I}_p  - \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{BB}'\mathbf{M}^{-1}\right)\mathbf{B} \\
&=\mathbf{I}_q+\mathbf{B}'\left(-\mathbf{I}_p + \frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{M}-\frac{1}{\sigma^2}\mathbf{BB'}\right)\mathbf{M}^{-1}\mathbf{B} \\
&=\mathbf{I}_q,
\end{align*}
so that with some small corrections your answer agrees with what you are calling the correct one.

Comment: Wow, I wonder how people learn those kind of identities?